# cURL awk { print } help

Tags: printing, curl, awk

I have this in a file:

```
<yweather:condition  text="Partly Cloudy"  code="29"  temp="56"  date="Wed, 23 Feb 2011 6:53 pm MST" />
```

I'm using this code to try and print "Partly Cloudy", although only "Partly" is not getting printed.

```
grep "yweather:condition" ~/Documents/weather.dat | awk '{ print $2 }' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[\"]" } ; { print $2 } '
```

Hopefully someone can explain how to get both words to print. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat ~/Documents/weather.dat |awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[\"]" } ; /yweather:condition/ { print $2 } '
```

Replaces all that

Answer (score 3):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//@text" ~/Documents/weather.dat 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Great answer. I didn't know about that program before, and I just added it to my toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "<yweather:condition  text="Partly Cloudy"  code="29"  temp="56"  date="Wed, 23 Feb 2011 6:53 pm MST" />" | awk '/weather/{gsub(/.*text=|code=.*/,"")}1'
Partly Cloudy

$ echo "<yweather:condition  text="Partly Cloudy"  code="29"  temp="56"  date="Wed, 23 Feb 2011 6:53 pm MST" />" | ruby -e 'puts gets.scan(/text=(.*)code=/)'
Partly Cloudy
```

If you have more complex situations, use a real XML/HTML parser.